# Problem with C# interfaces and inheritance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, interface, properties

I have the following interface I want to implement in a class:

```
public interface IAgro {
     AgroState agroState { get; }
}
```

The problem is that instead of implementing AgroState in the class using the interface I want my property to implement a different class which inherits from AgroState

```
public class E1_AgroState : AgroState
{
...
}

public class BasicWalkingEnemy : Entity, IAgro
{
    public E1_AgroState agroState { get; }

}
```

This is something I am used to do in Swift with protocols, for example, but C# compiler complains with

> 'BasicWalkingEnemy' does not implement interface member 'IAgro.agroState'. 'BasicWalkingEnemy.agroState' cannot implement 'IAgro.agroState' because it does not have the matching return type of 'AgroState'. [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS0738)

For now one solution I found is doing it like:

```
public class BasicWalkingEnemy : Entity, IAgro
{
    public AgroState agroState { get { return _agroState; } }
    public E1_AgroState _agroState { get; private set; }
}
```

But I think that is very inelegant. 
Is there a better solution to my problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically the way you'd do this is with *explicit interface implementation* so that anyone who only knows about your object via `IAgro` will just see `AgroState`, but any code that knows it's working with `BasicWalkingEnemy` will get `E1_Agrostate`:

```cs
// Note: property names changed to comply with .NET naming conventions
public class BasicWalkingEnemy : Entity, IAgro
{
    // Explicit interface implementation
    AgroState IAgro.AgroState => AgroState;

    // Regular property
    public E1_AgroState AgroState { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: And I always wondered what the explicit implementation was good for (I mean besides equal names in different interfaces), just learned something extremely helpful, thanks a lot!